# how to extract the text from the following HTML code?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping for a DS project, and i am using **BeautifulSoup** for that. But i am unable to extract the Duration from "tbody" tag in "table" class.
Following is the HTML code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Stipend</th>
                <th>Posted On</th>
                <th>Apply By</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="start-date-first">Immediately</div>
                </td>
                <td>1 Month</td>
                <td class="stipend_container_table_cell"> <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
                1500 /month
                </td>
                <td>26 May'20</td>
                <td>23 Jun'20</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Note : for extracting 'Immediately' text, i use the following code :

```
x = container.find("div", {"class" : "table-responsive"})
x.table.tbody.tr.td.div.text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use select() function to find tags by **css selector**.

```python
tds = container.select('div > table > tbody > tr > td')
# or just select('td'), since there's no other td tag

print(tds[1].text)
```

The return value of select() function is the list of all HTML tags that matches the selector. The one you want to retrieve is second one, so using index `1`, then get text of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "yourUrlHere"

pageRaw = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageRaw , 'lxml')
print(soup.table)
```

In my code i use lxml library to parse the data.  If you want to install `pip install lxml`... or just change into your libray in this part of the code:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(pageRaw , 'lxml')`

This code will return the first table ok?

Take care